# Select by index with selenium webdriver does not work

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select the option 0 (5Gallon) but I get **element not visible Exception.**

*Please note: `Wait` statements are added.*

```
<Select id="attrValue_ATT_calc_size__volume_or_weight_+_item_" onchange="JavaScript:productDisplayJS.hideMessage();productDisplayJS.setSKUImageId(&quot;productMainImage&quot;);productDisplayJS.setSelectedAttribute(&quot;Size&quot;,this.value, &quot;entitledItem_261730&quot;); productDisplayJS.notifyAttributeChange(&quot;261730&quot;,&quot;entitledItem_261730&quot;,false,true);productDisplayJS.updatePriceInfo(&quot;261730&quot;);productDisplayJS.updateItemDetails(&quot;entitledItem_261730&quot;);" style="display: none;">
  <option value="5 Gallon"> 5 Gallon</option>
  <option value="1 Gallon" selected="selected">1 Gallon</option>
</select>
```

I am using this function for selectdropbyindex:

```
public boolean selectDropdownItemByIndex(WebElement ddElement, int index) 
{
    boolean success = true;
    softAssert.setCause(null);
    try {
        Select selectElement = new Select(ddElement);
        int optionCount = selectElement.getOptions().size();
         (selectElement).selectByIndex(index);
    } catch (Exception | Error e) {
        ConsoleLog.error("Selecting an item in a dropdown Select menu did not work as expected.", e);
}
```

Comment: But your element is not visible! Check the html part `style="display: none;"`

Comment: so if the display is none do u think this way of selecting by index will not work

Comment: If the element is not visible you're not able to select the value using selenium. The way to do it is executing a javascript line, or forcint the element become visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("attrValue_ATT_calc_size__volume_or_weight_+_item_"))).selectByIndex(0);
```

Comment: It gives me the Optioncount as 2 as it has 2 options to select but (selectElement).selectByIndex(index) is failing and getting an exception